# How to stop updating the field or variable in object while copyToRealmOrUpdate in realm

Tags: android, realm, insert-update

```
Pojo Class:

public class ChannelResponse extends RealmObject{
   private RealmList<TvChannel> tv_channel;
}

public class TvChannel extends RealmObject{
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String stream_display_name;
private String stream_icon;
private String streaming_url;
private int isFavorite;
}
```

here isFavorite is int which should not get updated while updation of other fields when i get from API channelResponse and in api json object TvChannel dosent have isFavorite feild.

i am updating like this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(channelResponse);
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```

Comment: Query the object if it exists, save out its `isFavorite` into a boolean variable, say`copyToRealmOrUpdate()` and set the `isFavorite` value you saved on the proxy that was returned by `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`?

Comment: You can't update partially an object using `copyToRealmOrUpdate`.

As suggested, you can query for it, then update whatever fields you want. 

If you still want to use `copyToRealmOrUpdate` then you need to redesign your model to dissociate the concept of `isFavorite`.
 
You can have a POJO defining only TV Channels, and model a class that holds the list of preferred channels per user for example. This way you separate the concern of updating channels details, from the user building up his favourite list

Answer (score 0):

Have you apply @Ignore to the isFavorite field before ?

Comment: if i apply @Ignore then i will not be able to save or retrive the data in realm db for favorite using realm query.

Comment: did you allow null for isFavorite?

Comment: its integer by default it sets 0. my question is while update its should not update isFavorite field.

Answer (score 0):

Query the object if it exists

if yes, save out its isFavorite into a boolean variable

say copyToRealmOrUpdate()

you receive a proxy

then call `setFavorite(isFavorite)` on the proxy you received from  copyToRealmOrUpdate().